# jQuery Datepicker background color for cells based on event type

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

I need to show non available dates in different color based on the event type or if it is full booked for that day.

Below example fetches dates from database and i pass them as an array to JavaScript at present i am passing four parameter in an array  `[2012,7, 15, 'Some events']` such as Year, Month, Day & Years. I want to alter this array to pass Fifth parameter as color `[2012,7, 15, 'Some events', 'Red']`. so that i can change the color of the cell based on the event type.

I am not sure how i will alter below script to make it work. I have looked for example but could not find a matching one. I would appreciate help in this regard as i am not a Guru of Scripting.

```
function BindEvents()
{
//Script for Calendar
        var holiDays = [[2012,7, 15, 'Some events'],[2012,7, 4, 'Some Event'],[2012,7, 1, 'Full Booked'],[2012,7, 5, 'Full Booked']];
        $(function () {
            $("#txtBookDate").datepicker({
                dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",
                minDate: "-0d",
                maxDate: "+90d",
                firstDay: 0,
                beforeShowDay: noWeekendsOrHolidaysOrBlockedDates
            });

            function noWeekendsOrHolidaysOrBlockedDates(date) {
                //var noWeekend = jQuery.datepicker.noWeekends(date);
                return setHoliDays(date);
            }

            // set holidays function which is configured in beforeShowDay
            function setHoliDays(date) {
                var day = date.getDay();
                if (day == 5 || day ==6) return [false, ''];

                for (i = 0; i < holiDays.length; i++) {
                    if (date.getFullYear() == holiDays[i][0]
                        && date.getMonth() == holiDays[i][1] - 1
                        && date.getDate() == holiDays[i][2]) {
                        return [false, 'holiday', holiDays[i][3]];
                    }
                }
                return [true, ''];
            }
        });
}

BindEvents();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the [fine manual](http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#option-beforeShowDay):

> **beforeShowDay**
>
> A function that takes a date as a parameter and must return an array with:
>
> - `[0]`: `true`/`false` indicating whether or not this date is selectable
> - `[1]`: a CSS class name to add to the date's cell or `""` for the default presentation
> - `[2]`: an optional popup tooltip for this date
>
> The function is called for each day in the datepicker before it is displayed.

So there's no room in the return value for a specific color. However, element one of the array can contain multiple class names so you can do it through CSS.

If you wanted a particular holiday to come out in red text then you could do this in your `beforeShowDay`:

```
return [false, 'holiday red', holiDays[i][3]];
```

and then add a tiny bit of CSS:

```
td.red span.ui-state-default {
    color: #f00;
}
```

to make the `red` class do something.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/pjJGf/

Comment: Appreciate your answer, I can use your approach to get the desired result. Thanks

Comment: Wait, where is 'holiday red'??? Isn't that supposed to be a css class in this case?

Comment: @ApoorvKansal: That's *two* classes (e.g. http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/pjJGf/232/), you can [`addClass`](http://api.jquery.com/addClass/) and [`removeClass`](http://api.jquery.com/removeClass/) multiple classes at once by working with space delimited lists.