# Change cell color on click in datepicker plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am using jQuery plugin for datepicker. I was unable to change the background color of a date cell selected on clicking.

I even modified the css but not succeeded.

Comment: See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2906266/how-to-change-the-cell-color-of-a-jquery-datepicker) and [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11175036/jquery-datepicker-background-color-for-cells-based-on-event-type) if you find a good answer

Comment: -1 for the lack of information. When posting, try to add more specific information, like code-snippets, what you have tried, etc. Posting a general problem will most probably result in a general answer.

Answer (score 0):

The clicked cell in jQuery’s datepicker has a class of `ui-state-active`. You could style the background colour with something like:

```
.ui-datepicker-calendar .ui-state-active { background: red; }
```

Comment: Thanks Robin.  I hve preselected dates whose background is blue and i want the change of background color of default td on selecting the date

Comment: I’m not sure I understand. Can you put some code up so we can get a better idea of what you’re trying to do?